Check if a potentially primitive value has a given property
How do I check if a variable contains a certain property?
Let's assume:
var x = 'some string';

Then I would like to do:
if ('trim' in x)

but that gives me a:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'trim' in string

I can make it work by using:
'trim' in x.__proto__

but according to MDN __proto__ is deprecated and its use is (quote) "controversial and discouraged".
How can I achieve this then?
I have tried to use Object.keys(x) but that only lists the keys that are valid as indexes, not the properties.
I know that, in this specific example, I could simply use typeof x === 'string' but that's not a universal solution.

Is this variable a string or an object?

You can use Object.getPrototypeOf.
So 'trim' in Object.getPrototypeOf(x) returns true.

why not x.trim

@JaromandaX I guess potential duck-typing reasons. You might want to check for a property that might be on a primitive or object. And if it's there use it. But primitives don't work with in. And x.someProp doesn't necessarily mean it's missing, e.g. { someProp: undefined }

@rawstream but that won't work when x = { trim() { /* do something */ } }

So if i'm reading this right, you want to check if a string contains a substring?
In Javascript the function .includes exists.
Example: string.includes(substring)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

@AnthonyHeremans that's not at all what the question is about? It clearly says and demonstrates checking for a property.

@derstauner It may or may not be an instance of an Object, but either way it is an object, as are basically all thins in js.

@LukasKroess is optional chaining an option for this problem?

@LãNgọcHải good input, but sadly not applicable in my szenario

If for some reason you want to avoid directly accessing the property via x[prop], you could first pass the value to the Object function before testing with in.


let x = 'some string';
console.log(x != null && 'trim' in Object(x));




Why did you change your answer to include a check for null? If x = null your original answer works just fine, doesn't it? (returning false)

@LukasKroess "toString" in Object(null) is true

@LukasKroess Object(null) or Object(undefined) returns an empty object, such that you would get 'toString' in Object(null) to be true.

@VLAZ (+also @Unmitigated) I see. Thank you both for the heads up.

The in operator does not work with primitive values. There is also Reflect.has() which does the same as in but it also has the same limitation.
However, a simple way to go around it is to pass the values through the Object constructor without using new. Doing that will convert primitives to their wrapper classes while if the input is an object, it gets returned as-is. So, Object("a string") is the same as new String("a string") but Object({ some: "object" }) is the same as { some: "object" }. And this will allow lookups via in (or Reflect.has()) on those values.
One caveat is that Object(null) or Object(undefined) will create a plain object. Which will potentially return a false positive for something like "toString in Object(null). Since those two values cannot have properties, they can be excluded from the check with
target != null && prop in Object(target)

Demo:


const prop = "trim";

function propIn(target, prop) {
  return target != null && prop in Object(target);
}

const string = "a string";
const number = 42;
const bigint = 42n;
const boolean = true;
const symbol = Symbol("a symbol");
const obj = {an: "object"};
const objWithProp = {trim() { return "object with a .trim() method"; } }

console.log( propIn(string     , prop));
console.log( propIn(number     , prop));
console.log( propIn(bigint     , prop));
console.log( propIn(boolean    , prop));
console.log( propIn(symbol     , prop));
console.log( propIn(null       , prop));
console.log( propIn(undefined  , prop));
console.log( propIn(obj        , prop));
console.log( propIn(objWithProp, prop));
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }




You can verify if any variable has a property like the function hasProperty in the snippet below.


function hasProperty ( mySubject, myProperty )
{
  if ( ! ((mySubject === null) || (mySubject === undefined)) )
  {
    if ( (typeof mySubject == 'function') || (typeof mySubject == 'object') )
    {
      return Reflect.has(mySubject, myProperty);
    }
    
    else if ( typeof mySubject[myProperty] != 'undefined' )
    {
      // Note that here mySubject is a primitive value.
      // Properties can not be defined in primitives, but
      // can be defined on primitive prototypes.
      return true;
    }
  }
  
  return false;
}

// TESTING //

const mySubject1 = 'Anything goes here';
const mySubject2 = 300;
const mySubject3 = new Object;
const mySubject4 = undefined;
const mySubject5 = { valueOf: undefined };
const mySubject6 = Object.create(null);

mySubject6.valueOf = Object.prototype.valueOf;

console.log('mySubject1 =', mySubject1);
console.log('mySubject2 =', mySubject2);
console.log('mySubject3 =', mySubject3);
console.log('mySubject4 =', mySubject4);
console.log('mySubject5 =', mySubject5);
console.log('mySubject6 =', mySubject6);

console.log('Is mySubject1.valueOf defined?', hasProperty(mySubject1, 'valueOf'));
// Outputs: Is mySubject1.valueOf defined? true

console.log('Is mySubject2.valueOf defined?', hasProperty(mySubject2, 'valueOf'));
// Outputs: Is mySubject2.valueOf defined? true

console.log('Is mySubject3.valueOf defined?', hasProperty(mySubject3, 'valueOf'));
// Outputs: Is mySubject3.valueOf defined? true

console.log('Is mySubject4.valueOf defined?', hasProperty(mySubject4, 'valueOf'));
// Outputs: Is mySubject3.valueOf defined? false

console.log('Is mySubject5.valueOf defined?', hasProperty(mySubject5, 'valueOf'));
// Outputs: Is mySubject5.valueOf defined? true

console.log('Is mySubject6.valueOf defined?', hasProperty(mySubject6, 'valueOf'));
// Outputs: Is mySubject6.valueOf defined? true



Note that you can use Reflect.has(obj, prop). But if obj do not pass obj instanceof Object then an exception will be thrown, which is what happens when using mySubject1, mySubject2 or mySubject4 as the obj parameter.

Please explain how this solves the issue. Code-only answers are not  good answers

@DarkBee I'd say this one might be. Also I asked for 'how can I check' and he replied with 'you can check like this' and then provides the code. what else did you expect him to write?

"You can check like this" is not an answer. Answers are not meant for OP the exclusively but also for future readers stumbling upon a similar issue.

typeof mySubject[myProperty] != 'undefined' does not tell you if a propert is missing. It could be present but its value might be undefined: consider obj = { hello: undefined } then hasProperty(obj, "hello") and hasProperty(obj, "world") both return false but only one of those properties is missing.

@VLAZ Thank you. I edited the script and now it's complete. It will work in any case now.

"Properties can not be defined in primitives." They could...sort of. Choosing to ignore those is a design decision you can take. But it should be an informed decision.

mySubject instanceof Object - I wouldn't do that. I'd just go with mySubject != null && (typeof mySubject === "object" || typeof mySubject === "function"). Sure, more wordy but just stick it in a function like isObject. If you're using a library like Lodash it's already there. It's then 100% correct. As it stands Object.create(null) will fail that test. There might be other bizarre cases where it will also fail.

To check if a variable contains a certain property or method, you can use the typeof operator in combination with Object.getPrototypeOf() to safely access the prototype without using proto. Here's how you can do it:
var x = 'some string';

function hasMethod(obj, method) {
    return typeof Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)[method] === 'function';
}

if (hasMethod(x, 'trim')) {
    console.log("The string has the 'trim' method.");
} else {
    console.log("The string does not have the 'trim' method.");
}

Object.getPrototypeOf(obj): This gets the prototype of the object without using the deprecated proto.
typeof ... === 'function': This checks if the specified method exists and is indeed a function.
This approach is versatile and can be used to check for methods on any object, not just strings. Just pass the object and the method name as a string to the hasMethod function.

hasMethod({trim() { return "has a trim method" } }, "trim") will return false
